# Putting link of full text of paper in Google Scholar

Tags: google-scholar

I have several papers in IEEE Xplore. I have uploaded their pre-print versions in academia.edu. But when I search in Google Scholar, I can't find the links of those I uploaded in academia.

What should I do to show up the link of my free papers alongside with the original published ones in Google Scholar search? Where should I upload the free versions?
I am an undergrad student and I do not have any official website/e-mail.

Comment: Do people in your field use arXiv?  That could be a good option.

Comment: nope... Is there any other options ?

Comment: Be patient.  It may take time for Google to update their index.

Answer (score 5):

If the preprint version of the paper has been indexed by Google Scholar, then Scholar should show that version of the paper as well.  Assuming that it's permissable under the publisher's rules, you could post the paper on your personal web site and Scholar would eventually find and index it.  However, you can't explicitly add anything to Scholar's index.

Comment: *However, you can't explicitly add anything to Scholar's index* - Not strictly true, you can [request inclusion](https://support.google.com/scholar/troubleshooter/2898950) of a site, including a personal site.

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can tell, your IEEE Xplore papers and Academia.edu papers *do* appear on your Google Scholar profile. You simply need to click "All *x* versions" once you've selected the paper.